# Probability measure of rank-$r$ matrices

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, matrix-rank

I have a question about the distribution of matrices with a specific rank. Consider $\mathcal{M}^{n\times m}$ the set of all $n \times m$ matrices with entries in some field $\mathbb{K}$. If I define a $\sigma$-algebra composed of the subsets of $\mathcal{M}^{n\times m}$, with a probability measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\mathcal{M}^{n\times m}) = 1$, how to determine the measure $\mu(\mathcal{M}_{r}^{n\times m})$ of $m\times n$ rank-$r$ matrices?

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel algebra. Put $A = \{M \in \mathbb K^{n\times m}|rank\ M < \min(n,m)\},$ i.e. $A$ is the set of all matrices which don't have maximal possible rank. Then $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero. This follows from the fact that the rank of a matrix is determined by the vanishing resp. non-vanishing of determinants square submatrices. Determinants are polynomials in matrix entries, and the zero set of a polynomial is closed. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Density).

Comment: [continued] So, if the probability measure $\mu$ from your question has a Lebesgue density, we have $\mu(M_r^{n\times m}) = 0$ for $r < \min(n,m).$